# How can I connect to a Wowza Transcoder stream in JWPlayer?

Tags: audio, streaming, jwplayer, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I'm trying to pick up an audio-only transcoded stream from my Wowza server in JWPlayer.

At the moment, I know that the normal ( non-transcoded ) stream is making it through the server and back to my JWPlayer client - what I can't figure out is why I can't reach the audio-only stream.

JWPlayer code as follows:

```
        var PlayerInstance = jwplayer('jwcontainer').setup({
        image: '/resource/javascript/jwplayer/background.png',
        height: '420',
        width: '420',
        skin: 'stormtrooper',
        autostart: '1',
        androidhls: true,
        provider: 'rtmp',
        playlist: 
        [{
            sources: 
            [

                { file: 'http://SERVER:80/APPLICATION/flv:STREAM' },
                { file: 'http://SERVER:1935/APPLICATION/STREAM/playlist.m3u8' },
                { file: 'http://SERVER:1935/APPLICATION/STREAM/manifest.mpd' },
                { file: 'http://SERVER:1935/APPLICATION/STREAM/manifest.f4m' }
            ]
        }],
        rtmp:
        {
            bufferlength: 1,
            securetoken: ''
        }
    });
```

I've tried providing JWPlayer 'STREAM_aac' ( as implied by the Wowza Transcoder configuration? ) as my stream name, and come back with an 'ID not found on server' error.

I've also tried giving it an AAC 'stream type' ( replacing the 'flv:' with 'aac:' ), as well as MP3 ( just for kicks ) to no avail.

Any suggestions? Am I missing something?

Does anyone have a Working example of JWPlayer receiving a Wowza transcoded stream?

Comment: Can you post your transcoding template or a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot extract a both audio and audio/video streams from one Wowza application. In order to do so, you can ingest two steams to your Wowza server one with audio only and one with audio/video.

I found this post useful from [this](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?18370-extract-audio-stream-from-live-stream) Wowza community forum thread :

> There are other ways to get both an A/V stream and an audio-only
> stream.
>
> 1. Use ffmpeg. Input 1 stream, send 2 streams to Wowza, one of which is audio-only.
> 2. Use Wowza 3.0.5+. You can turn off audio or video tracks in your Application.xml.
>
> I have tested it and it works, like so:
>
> 1. Publish FMLE stream named "myStream" to Wowza "live" application.
> 2. Create a new live application called "livenovideo".
> 3. Turn off video the Application.xml for the "livenovideo" application.
> 4. Create a live.stream file containing "rtsp://localhost:1935/live/myStream
> 5. Use StreamManager to start "live.stream" on application "livenovideo."
>
> Playback audio+video: rtmp://[Wowza-IP]/live/myStream
>
> Playback audio only: rtmp://[Wowza-IP]/livenovideo/live.stream